# Logic in merge tags, Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, logical-operators, gravity-forms-plugin

I am creating a few Notifications in Gravity Forms and I would like to use some "if/else" logic based on field entries.

For example, I have a Buyer 1 Name field and a checkbox that asks "Would you like to add another buyer?"  When they check it, a new Name field appears for Buyer 2. In my Notification I would like to say "The following buyer...." if only the first name is completed, and "The following buyers..." if the 2nd name is filled in.  Basically make buyer plural.  I could give about 10 more examples of needing logic INSIDE the merge tags, really surprised this isn't available. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a Gravity Forms conditional shortcode in your notification message. It looks like this:

```
[gravityforms action="conditional" merge_tag="{Field:1}" condition="is" value="desired value"]Show this content if the field is equal to the field value I specified earlier[/gravityforms]
```

You can also check out this [full tutorial](https://gravityplus.pro/how-to/setup-gravity-forms-conditional-confirmation-or-notification-messages-based-on-submitted-values/) (images included).

Comment: I was hoping you would answer this Naomi, I have seen your other answers :).  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This should help too.  http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/gravity-forms/user-guides/getting-started/shortcodes/#conditional-shortcode.  I used ...condition="isnot" value=""... to test for empty items